# Will putting a 5x115 lug pattern wheel on 5x114.3 fit?

Tags: wheels, hyundai, elantra, spare-tire, wheel-lugs

If it fits, will driving with it cause any damage? It is intended as a full-size spare, though I might consider getting a full set in the future. The car is 2008 Hyundai Elantra SE. I'm finding no other cars with the exact specs on the wheel (16", 6" width, 5x114.3mm, 54 offset).

I know it's not good to deviate much from the offset as well.

Comment: Hub size the same?

Comment: @rpmerf I'm not sure. Does it need to be?

Comment: yes.  There are hub rings in the event they are different.  Something to consider when looking at rims

Comment: you might have better luck in your search if you realise 114.3mm is 4.5 inch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl dr:** Don't use anything but the proper lug pattern/size.

The biggest problem with using a lug pattern which doesn't match exactly is you will most likely *never* get the wheel to align correctly. It will almost always be off center. The reason? The lug holes are sized to be centered exactly on the lugs themselves (seems obvious, right?). When the lug pattern is off, the first lug you tighten will throw the alignment of the other (in your case) four lugs out from the center of their lug holes.

Even if you were able to get all five lugs *even* (note I didn't say centered, because they will never be that way) in their lug holes, then only one little portion of one side of the lug will be engaging the lug hole correctly. If you get the holes to stretch enough to then be fully engaged to the lug nuts, then you're putting undue stress on the wheel. Adding stress onto the wheel where it doesn't belong can cause wheel failure, which could be deadly in the end.

Even the small amount of difference in wheel lug spacing can cause you big issues. Best idea ... don't even try it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say don't use it - but get it checked by a competent shop / garage they will tell you for sure.

I would consider going to the breakers / scrap yards and find the same car and source a good one that way and have it checked of course with your own tyre.